# How do I expose namespaced C++ string constants via SWIG? (C#)

Tags: c#, c++, string, swig

There are various ways of exposing namespaced compile-time constant strings in C++.

I have a bunch of these that I'd like to share between C++ and C# via SWIG, so that I can refer to them like this in C++:

```
Foo::Bar::SomeConstant
```

and like this in C#:

```
Foo.Bar.SomeConstant
```

I don't really care if the C++ side of things is `const char*` or `std::string`, but I do need the namespacing to avoid collisions.

I'd prefer to just bung this in a header file:

```
namespace Foo
{
    namespace Bar
    {
        const char* const SomeConstant = "hello world";
    }
}
```

But I can't seem to get the C# side of that to play ball using SWIG. What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by nesting structs in a namespace and giving them private constructors and public static const std::string members (populated in the separate cpp file).

This creates getters in the pinvoke generated code that SWIG wraps with static read-only C# properties with getters only, which is pretty much exactly what I want.

It's worth noting that you end up making a C# string every time you use the C# property (rather than it making a single static instance in C#-land), but that's fine for my use case.